# Запуск файла Java из IJ

Tags: java, linux

При нажатии на кнопу run выдает ошибку:

```
Abnormal build process termination: 
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/bin/java -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\" -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Dpreload.project.path=/home/mirai/Documents/проекты/Java0 -Dpreload.config.path=/home/mirai/.config/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3/options -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=-8099790356840864507 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2020.3 -Didea.home.path=/snap/intellij-idea-community/273 -Didea.config.path=/home/mirai/.config/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3 -Didea.plugins.path=/home/mirai/.local/share/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3 -Djps.log.dir=/home/mirai/.cache/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3/log/build-log -Djps.fallback.jdk.home=/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/jbr -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=11.0.9.1 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/mirai/.cache/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3/compile-server/java0_764dd557/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"/tmp/kotlin-idea-16499155253814599071-is-running\" -classpath /snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/lib/tools.jar org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher /var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/maven-resolver-provider-3.6.1.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/maven-resolver-spi-1.3.3.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/maven-model-builder-3.6.1.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic-1.3.3.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/httpclient-4.5.12.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/guava-29.0-jre.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-http-1.3.3.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/java/lib/jps-javac-extension-1.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.25.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/platform-api.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/maven-resolver-util-1.3.3.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/maven-resolver-api-1.3.3.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/resources_en.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/forms-1.1-preview.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.7.1.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/util.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.6.1.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/commons-lang3-3.10.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/annotations.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/qdox-2.0-M10.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/plexus-utils-3.2.0.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/maven-artifact-3.6.1.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/gson-2.8.6.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/log4j.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/jna.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/netty-common-4.1.52.Final.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/netty-codec-4.1.52.Final.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/maven-model-3.6.1.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/httpcore-4.4.13.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/jna-platform.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/maven-resolver-impl-1.3.3.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/jdom.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/idea_rt.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/maven-builder-support-3.6.1.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/asm-all-9.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-file-1.3.3.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/intellij-deps-fastutil-8.4.1-4.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/netty-resolver-4.1.52.Final.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/trove4j.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/netty-buffer-4.1.52.Final.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/nanoxml-2.2.3.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/lz4-java-1.7.1.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/protobuf-java-3.13.0.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/jps-model.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/gson-2.8.6.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/guava-29.0-jre.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.65.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.65.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/javax.activation-1.2.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.common-27.0.0.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-6.7.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/gson-2.8.6.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/guava-29.0-jre.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.65.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.65.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/lib/javax.activation-1.2.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.common-27.0.0.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-6.7.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/java-guiForms-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-common.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-common.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/java-langInjection-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-constants-rt.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/gradle-java/lib/gradle-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-jps-common.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-common.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/android/lib/apkzlib-4.0.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/android/lib/apksig-4.0.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-jps-plugin.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/android/lib/android-jps-model.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/android/lib/build-common.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/android/lib/android-rt.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.sdk-common-27.0.0.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.common-27.0.0.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.repository-27.0.0.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.sdklib-27.0.0.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.layoutlib-api-27.0.0.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/273/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.manifest-merger-27.0.0.0.jar org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 41243 f8980e62-163a-4155-b451-ae7917a135fb /home/mirai/.cache/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3/compile-server
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/bin/java: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/bin/java: не удаётся запустить бинарный файл
```

Подскажите как решить.
OS - Linux Manjaro KDE

Comment: а файл /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_281/bin/java существует и он "рабочий"?

Comment: да, рабочий и существует

Comment: то есть, если запустить в консоли оно что то выводит, не крешится?